# Mulitply Value in LookupOrderedRows()

Tags: ampscript, lookup

I want to create a Lookup which have to return two different values of a special Column.

For example:

```
Column1 Column2 
  01    .....
  02    .....
  03    .....
  02    .....
  04    .....
  01    .....
  02    .....
  03    .....
  02    .....
  04    .....
```

Now I want to return all rows which include `01` AND `04`

Would that be possible?

Currently I solved that problem with to filter

```
SET @subrow1 = LookupOrderedRows("SubjectsOverview",@subshow, "PubDate desc","Subjects", "01")
SET @subrow2 = LookupOrderedRows("SubjectsOverview",@subshow, "PubDate desc","Subjects", "04")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send multiple key value pairs to the Lookup functions in AMPscript. You should be able to use a single lookup:

```
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("SubjectsOverview",@subshow, "PubDate desc","Column1", "01", "Column2", "04")

set @rowCount = RowCount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
    /* do things here */
endif
```